# Where can I find a web development IDE with the following requirements?

Tags: node.js, macos, angularjs, ide

My goal is to create single page applications on my Mac book running OSX.

- Support for Angular.js / Node.js / TypeScript
- Ability to run on Mac OSX
- Free or cheap
- Support for debugging
- Ability to run locally for testing

Comment: this kind of question will get you a down vote here.. different devs have different opinions

Comment: One is WebStorm, Sublime, google it that is your best source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) from JetBrains. It provides code completition, syntax and error check for html, css, most JS libraries and even for CoffeeScript. It has an internal terminal to work with npm modules. It's compatible with some test environment such as Karma for AngularJS.

You can have an academic license for 26€ if you are a student.

Btw, if you want to work with PHP as well, I suggest you PHPStorm. It offers pretty much everything WebStorm offers plus PHP support.

Comment: This looks great! I will download the trial tonight and review more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. It's really a nice software...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like XCode for web purposes. On all my PC's I use sublime text 3, but that's too basic for heavy duty web development. A "mature" product, specialized on web languages for mac, featuring special things like live preview, code completion, folding, syntax checking etc, is Panic's Coda 2. (but you'll need to spend 75 bucks. Get the trial. It's worth it.)